# C# "Default" resolution of ambigious type name?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is there a way of applying a default resolution to all ambigious references to a class name in a project?

To set a bit of background, I'm working on a very large project with thousands of files which was built with .NET framework 3.5. The previous coder developed a `Tuple` type and put it in the `Utilities` namespace.

However, now we want to change it to use .NET framework 4, which has `System.Tuple` so I have thousands of errors stating that `Tuple` is ambigious reference (`Utilities.Tuple` and `System.Tuple`)

Rather than having to go through the codebase and change thousands of references to this class, is there a way of saying once for the project: "Whenever `Tuple` is used, use `Utilities.Tuple`" ?

Comment: Are you able to refactor the name of the Utilities.Tuple class **before** upgrading to 4? Or has a lot of other work already been done, making that too arduous to go back to square one?

Comment: Are the two compatible? If so, just delete `Utilities.Tuple` - it's highly likely that the places using it will already have a using directive for the `System` namespace.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well that depends on whether those existing uses were compatible. If the previous developer had seen .NET 4 and deliberately created something similar, it should be simple - that sounds like a very plausible scenario, but we can't tell whether or not it's actually the problem.

Comment: I think what you are suggesting "could" introduce some hideously un-maintainable code. - either deprecate Utilities.Tuple or explicitly change every line to Utilities.Tuple; the latter can be done with a solution wide search/replace

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That would be the reason for the ambiguous reference errors, right? And indeed, good point.

Comment: @BoltClock: Not necessarily - it will be ambiguous just referencing the simple type name `Tuple` if both `System` and `Utilities` namespaces have been imported. That would be the case whether or not the two are compatible. It's also not clear whether the OP is trying to avoid significant manual work, or significant changes in terms of number of files. Renaming the type in the working .NET 3.5 code (before upgrading to .NET 4.0) should be very simple, but generate very widespread changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution wide fix for this, but I can see three options for refactoring:

1. Refactor all code to use `System.Tuple` and deprecate `Utilities.Tuple`
2. add `using Tuple = Utilities.Tuple;` in each files using statements
3. Solution wide search/replace `Tuple` with `Utilites.Tuple`